# Convert string to date and use in a Where statement

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake portal and need to use the `sold_dt` field as criteria in my where statement.  But the `sold_dt` is stored as a `varchar` in (yyyymmdd) format.  I have tried the Convert with no success.  I get this error - `SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 8 invalid identifier 'DATETIME'`

```
select
  convert(datetime, a.sold_dt) as sold_date,
  count(a.vin)
from MyTable a
where sold_date >= '2020/04/01'
group by 1
limit 100
```

Comment: Try `to_date(a.sold_dt,'YYYYMMDD')`.

Comment: `select to_date('20200501','yyyymmdd');` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems your setting for date formats might be different that mine as I needed to change the WHERE clause to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, but this shows it working:

```
WITH example_data AS (
    select * from values ('20200501', 'VIN_A'), ('20200501', 'VIN_B') v(sold_dt, vin)
)
select
  to_date(a.sold_dt,'YYYYMMDD') as sold_date,
  count(a.vin)
from example_data a
where sold_date >= '2020-04-01'
group by 1
limit 100;
```

giving:

```
SOLD_DATE   COUNT(A.VIN)
2020-05-01  2
```